# Titanium Alloy only numeric keyboard

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How do I use only the keyboard with numeric only in Titanium Alloy (sdk 3.1.3)

because this is wrong:

```
KEYBOARDTYPE: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax is

```
keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app its perfect working. Try lowercase(KEYBOARDTYPE) or add returnKeyType.